# getActiveCell() always returns 1,1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know this has been asked before but none of the answers seem to be working for me. I need to get the values of cells that are clicked on. As a very basic prototype, I created a script tied to my spreadsheet with the following:

```
function getVal() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  Logger.log(sheet.getActiveCell().getValue());
}
```

I then go into my spreadsheet and select a cell with a value and run the function in the script window. No value is displayed in the log.

Next I tried:

```
function getVal() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  Logger.log(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow() + ',' + sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn());
}
```

I then go into my spreadsheet and select a cell with a value (G6) and run the function in the script window. The log displays `1,1`.

And finally I tried

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  Browser.msgBox(sheet.getActiveCell().getRow() + ',' + sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn());
}
```

I then go into my spreadsheet and select a cell with a value (G6) and make a change to it. When I hit enter, the popup dialog displays `1,1`.

This seems like it should be really simple but for the life of me cannot figure it out. Can anyone help?

Comment: `When I hit enter, the log displays 1,1.` Where does it display `1,1`? There is no `log` in the previous script.

Comment: Have you tried using the `getCurrentCell()` [method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getCurrentCell()) - it is even recommended by the official documentation over the `getActiveCell()` method?

Comment: @TheMaster - my bad - it is a msgBoox - edited post to reflect that.

Comment: @OlegValter - just tried `getCurrentCell` and `1,1` is still returned

Comment: Sorry, I know what's wrong - please, use the `getActiveSheet()` instead of `getSheets()[0]`. The latter doesn't contain any reference to active sheet and thus defaults to cell A1

Comment: @OlegValter - YESSSSSS! That as it. Duuuuhhh (on my part). If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Passer-By If it works, kindly undelete your answer.

Comment: No problem - It took me a while to understand that the `getSheets[0]` is the issue as well! (I can't see what's @Passer-By's answer was, but if it outlines the same issue and he restores it - please, accept it)

Comment: @TheMaster My apologies, I had seen you posted the comment right as I posted it as the answer and didn't want to just take the reputation and run with it - I've undeleted my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested this in a spreadsheet and I found that using `var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();` yielded the correct results whereas using the `.getSheets()[]` method did not.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit late, but I was researching this today, and wanted to share:  My issue was similar, in that `sheet.getActiveRange().getRow()`, `sheet.getActiveCell().getRow()`, etc., all returned row 1, regardless of what cell or range was active.

In this case, I was opening the script from a previous *bookmark* I created. Opening the script from a *bookmark* apparently doesn't re-establish the active relationship with the sheet.

Once I opened the script from the *spreadsheet* instead, my code returned the correct row reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried following code and works fine. getRow() method is of Range class not Sheet class.

```
var ActSpSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ActSheet  = ActSpSheet.getActiveSheet();

var GetCell = ActSheet.getCurrentCell();
var GetCurRow = GetCell.getRow();
Logger.log(GetCurRow);
```